# If x = (2+t)/(1+2t) and y = (3+t)/t, (a) prove that dy/dx = (1+2t)^2/t^2 (b) find the value of d^2y/dx^2 when x = 0

Tags: calculus

Can anyone help me with this problem??? My teacher always words his practice questions funny and I don't understand it!!

If $x = (2+t)/(1+2t)$ and $y = (3+t)/t$,

(a) prove that $dy/dx = (1+2t)^2/t^2$

(b) find the value of $d^2y/dx^2$ when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're supposed to take a couple of derivatives, divide some stuff and show that the second derivative your professor provided you  along with the one you got are the same.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get the answer i'm not that good at Calculus can you please break it down for me

Comment: So the second derivative of y with respect to the second derivative of x (d^2y)/(d^2x) is equal to the (d/dt) of (x'(t)/y'(t)) divided by x'(t)

Comment: I'm completely lost lol

Comment: What's the derivative of the x equation?

Comment: d/dx (2+t/1+2t) is the derivative of the x equation!

Comment: So take the derivative of that using the quotient rule!

Comment: I'm still not understanding can u just show me how to setup the problem correctly

Comment: Do you know how the take the derivative of a parametric function?

Comment: @Brandon0412 you just have to take the derivatives of the x equation and divide that by the derivative of the y equation.

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule (assuming $y$ is expressible as a function of $x$ then $y=f(x(t))$)

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$$

where by the quotient rule

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{1\cdot t-(3+t)1}{t^2}=\frac{-3}{t^2}$$
and
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1(1+2t)-(2+t)2}{t^2}=\frac{-3}{(1+2t)^2}$$
so
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(1+2t)^2}{t^2}$$
as required.

Now the second derivative is

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx/dt}$$

where by the quotient and power rules

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{2(1+2t)t^2-(1+2t)^2(2t)}{t^4}=\frac{-4t^3-6t^2-2t}{t^4}=\frac{-2(t+1)(2t+1)}{t^3}$$

So then

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{2(t+1)(1+2t)^3}{3t^3}$$

Now $x=0 \implies t=-2$, so

$$\left.\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right|_{x=0}=\left.\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right|_{t=-2}=\frac{(2)(-1)(-3)^3}{(-2)^3}=-\frac{27}{4}$$